# How to add space between two unicode strings?

Tags: python, unicode, concatenation

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
separators = [u"।", u",", u"."]
dat=open(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\text4.txt",'r').read()
text=dat.decode("utf-8")
wros=text.split()
out=""
import string
space=" "
counter=0;
for word in wros:
        out=u" ".join(word)

writ=open("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\text5.txt",'w')
writ.write(out.encode('utf-8'))
writ.close()
```

text4.txt contains भारत का इतिहास काफी समृद्ध एवं विस्तृत है।
text5.txt outputs as ह ै ।

desired output is भारत का इतिहास काफी समृद्ध एवं विस्तृत है।

please tell me what i am doing is wrong ?
HElp required ! thanks in advance

Comment: how about you insert the space unicode after every `,` ?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `space=u"\u0020"`? Or you could just try something like `print ' '.join(w)`.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer  that would also help me but wouldnot that effect my running time?

Comment: yes it will but if its only 2 strings with that length, you won't realize any difference

Comment: @squeamishossifrage yes indeed but that also didnot helped but thanks

Comment: @XtremeBaumer exactly i have only shown a bit of problem but indeed the data is huge.

Comment: @imshashi17 Please explain. `print " ".join(w)` outputs `भारत का इतिहास काफी समृद्ध एवं विस्तृत` on my terminal. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: i don't have a different solution, which does not take more running time. that's why i would go with that solution

Comment: @squeamishossifrage that would print it that but intstead i want to  add it to str after operation what you are doing is you print a space then भारत and then in 2nd iter again a space followed by next word का  but i want to add all of them somewhere and then print that outputs without spaces

Comment: @imshashi17 Your question is unclear. You can assign `" ".join(w)` directly to another variable if that helps.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer but is not that also a part of problem or exactly what i want to do add space after " ," so new  series becomes w=[u'\ufeff\u092d\u093e\u0930\u0924', u'\u0020',u'\u0915\u093e',u'\u0020'] but thats what the error is it is not happening

Comment: @squeamishossifrage i am saying that when i add " ".join(w) to a variable that does produces the result. for word in wros :        out=" ".join(word)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `u"0200"` is `0200`, not space. If you want to use space, just assign `space = u" "`.

And if you want to join these words with space between them, simply run:

```
u" ".join(w)
```

Comment: Try to avoid mixing byte strings and Unicode, use `u" ".join(w)`.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the answer.

Comment: @MinhHoàng please review the question once more ..

Comment: @MarkRansom please look at the problem once more

Comment: @imshashi17 if you did `out = u" ".join(wros)` instead of your `for` loop you'd get your result, just as this answer says.

Comment: @MarkRansom but i need the loop to edit the contents

Comment: @imshashi17 then post a question that more closely matches your problem! How can you expect to get relevant help when you don't post a relevant question?

Comment: @MarkRansom i am so sorry i have just joined this community today only and i am flattered